# spree 0.70.3 rails 3.1.3 issue with taxonomy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

running spree 0.70.3 on rails 3.1.3

I create through the admin a new taxonomy tree, and then i add a taxon on a product.
The new taxon does it indeed show on the sidebar however when try to access i get 404 doesnt exist.

```
Started GET "/t/organa-metrisis/mikrometra" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-28 22:44:33 +0200
  Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."name" = 'brand' LIMIT 1
  Processing by TaxonsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"organa-metrisis/mikrometra"}
  AppConfiguration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "configurations".* FROM "configurations" WHERE "configurations"."type" IN ('AppConfiguration') AND "configurations"."name" = 'Default configuration' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Taxon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE "taxons"."permalink" = 'organa-metrisis/mikrometra' LIMIT 1
Rendered public/404.html (116.9ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 364ms (Views: 217.9ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running the same environment and rails, but my output is different, and works fine. I recommend re-creating your Taxonomy, and then re-assigning your Taxons on the product. It's possible that there's something wrong with your **_taxonomies.html.erb** view in "views/shared".

Here's my sample output (with 4 Taxons at the top level, and 8 Taxons at the 2nd level of one Taxon):

```
Started GET "/t/cards/congratulations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-18 22:11:26 -0500
  Property Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."name" = 'brand' LIMIT 1
  Processing by TaxonsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"cards/congratulations"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Taxon Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE "taxons"."permalink" = 'cards/congratulations' LIMIT 1
  Taxon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE "taxons"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  Taxon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" >= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" <= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  Taxonomy Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "taxonomies".* FROM "taxonomies" INNER JOIN "taxons" ON "taxons"."taxonomy_id" = "taxonomies"."id" AND "taxons"."parent_id" IS NULL
Taxon Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE "taxons"."taxonomy_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND ("taxons"."parent_id" IS NULL)
  Taxon Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE "taxons"."parent_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4) ORDER BY "lft"
  Taxon Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "taxons".* FROM "taxons" WHERE ("taxons"."lft" <= 8 AND "taxons"."rgt" >= 9) ORDER BY "taxons"."lft"
Rendered spree_dodatest_theme/app/views/shared/_taxonomies.html.erb (140.1ms)
```

... (it goes on)